# Getting error with AngularJS 1.4 NewRouter and Component Names

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

Trying to work with Angular 1.4's new router and ng-link and coming across a naming issue that I don't understand.

I have a component that I'd like to name 'statOrders'.  I've named the folder, .html, and .js files that same way - everything controllers etc.  I tried to be very consistent in that naming/casing.  I have setup my route as follows

```
{path: '/statOrders', component: 'statOrders' }
```

I am using an ng-link to go to that component as such:

```
<a ng-link="statOrders()"/>
```

I am getting an error that it cannot find 'stat-orders'. It is looking for a folder and js file with that naming.

I can get this to work if I just make the entire name lower case, but I'd rather not do that.  I have tried a number of things trying to figure this out.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

I have read about the normalization of directive names, but cannot see how to apply this to this particular scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This lets you override default conventions and configure how controllers are named and where templates are loaded from.
https://angular.github.io/router/$componentLoaderProvider

An example out in the wild.
http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/new-angular-router-naming-conventions/